# find duplicate indexes in list of dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates

I have a huge list of dictionaries inside it like these, wherein each dictionary has 4 keys.

```
l = [dict1 , dict2, dict3, dict4 .......]

dict1 = {'text': 'XYZ', 'x': 961, 'y': 420.59375, 'width': 141, 'height': 30}

dict2 = {'text': 'ABC', 'x': 962, 'y': 13.09375, 'width': 50, 'height': 33}

dict3 = {'text': 'XYZ', 'x': 961, 'y': 420.59375, 'width': 141, 'height': 30}

dict4 = {'text': 'ABC', 'x': 962, 'y': 13.09375, 'width': 50, 'height': 33}
```

I want to find all indexes of list whose `dict['x']` is same.

the initials approach that comes to my mind is O(n^2) approach wherein, I will be iterating each index and compare with every other index.

Please help me with any efficient approach if any

**Expected output:**

{0,2} since dict1 and dict3 have same x

{1,3} since dict2 and dict4 have same x

Comment: Provide expected output.

Comment: is your list a list of strings or the actual dictionaries? what have you tried?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar: updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and a for loop to make it `O(n)`:

```
l = [dict1 , dict2, dict3, dict4.......]

indexes = defaultdict(list)

for i, d in enumerate(l):
    indexes[d["x"]].append(i)
```

Comment: Just clarifying...I didn't do

Comment: Because it won't work, string indices must be integers, and you've reassigned `list` to an instance

Comment: @Sayse, the confusion comes at that he doesnt have strings, he have dictionaries inside the list. I just interpreted that from the question.

Comment: I have dict inside list, so list[i] is a dict

Comment: @Netwave: Accepted, I like this

Comment: I think the variable name `list` in `list = [dict1 , dict2, dict3, dict4.......]` should be changed. It is misleading in this example and will probably throw an error on `indexes = defaultdict(list)`.

Comment: @SupratimHaldar, indeed, and I was using `l` in the loop instead. thanks